# How to locate a tikz matrix at a particular point, besides xshift and yshift

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I am used to `\node[right=of SOME_OTHER_NODE]` and `\node[...] at (SOME_COORDINATE)` but these features don't seem available in `\matrix` and all I can figure out is to use `xshift` and `yshift`. Is there another way? For example I would like to locate the `jetsam` matrix below at `(jetsam_link |- flotsam.north west)` but can't figure out how to do it.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
       >=latex,
       scale=1.2,
    open circle/.style={
        circle, inner sep=0pt,
        thick,draw=black,
        fill = white,
    },
    junction/.style={open circle, minimum size=0.5mm,fill=black, node distance=5mm},
    table/.style={
        matrix of nodes,
        nodes={draw=black, font={\ttfamily}, align=left, anchor=center, 
            text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.5ex, inner sep=1mm},
        column sep=0,row sep=0, inner sep=0,
        anchor=north west
    },
    kvmap/.style={
        table,
        column 1/.style={text width=2cm},
        column 2/.style={text width=1.5cm},
    },
    list/.style={
        table,
        column 1/.style={text width=2cm},
    }
]
\matrix (root) [kvmap, nodes={fill=white!70!yellow}]
{
foo & 37 \\
bar & {} \\
baz & "hey" \\
quux & {} \\
flotsam & {} \\
jetsam & {} \\
};

\matrix (bar) [kvmap, nodes={fill=white!70!yellow},
    xshift=5cm, yshift=2cm,
]{
name & "Jason" \\
color & "yellow" \\
};

\matrix (quux) [kvmap, nodes={fill=white!70!yellow},
    xshift=5cm, yshift=0.5cm,
]{
fears & {} \\
};

\matrix (fears) [list, nodes={fill=white!70!yellow},
    xshift=10cm, yshift=0.5cm,
]{
"clowns" \\
"fire" \\
"poverty" \\
};

\matrix (flotsam) [kvmap, nodes={fill=white!70!yellow},
    xshift=5cm, yshift=-1.3cm,
    column 2/.style={text width=3cm},   
]{
origin & "New York" \\
destination & "San Francisco" \\
};

\matrix (jetsam) [list, nodes={fill=white!70!yellow},
    xshift=5cm, yshift=-2.59cm,
]{
1 \\
2 \\
3 \\
};


\node[junction](root_link) at ($(root-1-1.north west) + (-5mm,10mm)$){};
\node[junction](bar_link) at (root-2-2){};
\node[junction](quux_link) at (root-4-2){};
\node[junction](flotsam_link) at (root-5-2){};
\node[junction](jetsam_link) at (root-6-2){};
\node[junction](fears_link) at (quux-1-2){};

\draw[thick, ->] (root_link) |- (root-1-1.west);
\draw[thick, ->] (bar_link) -- (bar_link -| root.east) -- ++(2mm,0) |- (bar-1-1.west);
\draw[thick, ->] (quux_link) -- (quux_link -| root.east) -- ++(4mm,0) |- (quux-1-1.west);
\draw[thick, ->] (fears_link) -- (fears-1-1.west);
\draw[thick, ->] (flotsam_link) -- (flotsam_link -| root.east) -- ++(6mm,0) |- (flotsam-1-1.west);
\draw[thick, ->] (jetsam_link) -- (jetsam_link -| root.east) -- ++(6mm,0) |- (jetsam-1-1.west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Oh, never mind, somehow I didn't get the syntax right; this works.

```
\matrix (jetsam) [list, nodes={fill=white!70!yellow},
] at (root-6-1.north -| flotsam.north west) {
1 \\
2 \\
3 \\
};
```